# Sending from secondary domains in same BU

Tags: marketing-cloud, sender-authentication-package

I want to be able to send emails from another domain (that is not my SAP domain) in the same BU.

Can this be achieved be achieved by purchasing a private domain? What if we already own the domain, can we delegate a subdomain (similar to SAP domain) and are there any other considerations to make? (i.e. RMM or CloudPages URLs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, this can be done through the Private Domain SKU.

It's totally okay if you already own the domain, in these cases your domain owner/local IT will need to make some changes to allow ExactTarget to be able to send through this domain name. All requirements are generally provided by the SFMC Deliverability Team.

Now there is one limitation with Private Domains - you can only have it either for Email sends, meaning it's a domain you can use for your From Address(es) **or** you can have it on your Cloud page domain configuration.

Read more about this on their documentation - [**Private Domain overview**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000240073&language=en_US&type=1).

RMM will depend on your configuration, although as far as I know you can configure it the same way as you do with SAP domain. Including the option to enable Direct Forwards.